# How do I install a package with aptitude?

Tags: command-line, package-management, packaging, aptitude

I've looked at an aptitude [tutorial](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/22/installing-linux-applications-with-aptitude/) and read the man page, but I just don't get it.  After you launch aptitude, how do you say "install package foo"?  Or search for all packages with "foo" in their name?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After running aptitude, use these key commands as found at [Using aptitude GUI style](http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude): (If you use Bionic, use <kbd>CTRL+T</kbd> instead of <kbd>F10</kbd>)

> <kbd>F10</kbd> to access the aptitude menu.
>
> <kbd>?</kbd> this is to access "help"
>
> Use 'up' <kbd>↑</kbd>, 'down' <kbd>↓</kbd> , 'left' <kbd>←</kbd>, 'right' <kbd>→</kbd>, to navigate.
>
> Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select items.
>
> Use <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> to install, update, or remove a package
>
> Use <kbd>g</kbd> to preview or confirm actions
>
> <kbd>q</kbd> to quit – this will also close the currently open window (<kbd>g</kbd> goes forward, <kbd>q</kbd> goes back)

The common use of aptitude in TUI (text user interface) is:

1. run aptitude;
2. press <kbd>u</kbd> (update the lists of available packages);
3. press <kbd>U</kbd> (Mark all upgradable packages to be upgraded);
4. (search/select some stuff to install, is optional);
5. press <kbd>g</kbd> (to see the pending actions and modify if needed);
6. press <kbd>g</kbd> (again, to start the download).

Some time when you need to resolve conflicts, you discover that you made a mistake;

you can easily use 'Cancel pending actions' in the 'Actions' menu so that you can re-select.

When reviewing pending actions:

> <kbd>a</kbd> explicitly accepts an action (use again to unaccept)
>
> <kbd>r</kbd> rejects an action
>
> <kbd>g</kbd> again goes ahead with pending actions

## Using aptitude from the command line like apt-get

To install a package on a console run:

```
aptitude install package name
```

To search packages:

```
aptitude search package name
```

For example, let's say you want to install Pidgin

Search:

```
aptitude search pidgin
```

Install:

```
aptitude install pidgin
```

Comment: The `F10` key don't work on Bionic, it `ctrl + t` that does that now!

Comment: The answer was written long before Bionic. I have updated with your information

Answer (score 3):

To search for a package, hit `/` and enter a part of the package name you want to search (regexps can be used). This is similar to search in editors like vim.

You can use the up- and down-arrow keys for browsing, together with enter for toggling the tree nodes.

When you have found the right package, hit `+` to mark it for installation (it will be shown in green and you see an `i` as the second character in the status column). Then type `g` (for "go") to get to the preview screen showing all pending changes. A second `g` will start the installation.

You can also use enter when on a package to open a window with details of the package.

When there are more than one windows open in aptitude (like the package details and preview windows), you switch between them with `F6` and `F7`, and close the current window with `q`.

Comment: well, I can't think of anything to install!  However, I'll check it out more later.  Why don't the man pages say something simple like that?  very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

With `aptitude` you can use the ncurses based console in the terminal (see the other answers for that) or use all of its options on the command line. I usually use the latter method, as I'll demonstrate using the example of the `cheese` package:

(**Before** using any of the `aptitude` *install* commands in this article it is worth running `sudo aptitude update` to refresh the list of available software.)

To search for a package, use

```
aptitude search cheese
```

Then to show all the package information concerning versions and dependencies, type

```
aptitude show cheese
```

Then to install it use

```
sudo aptitude install cheese
```

However, beyond the standard basic usage of searching, removing, and installing packages, `aptitude` can install and remove packages with one command. With `aptitude` install commands add `-` after the package name to have it *removed*, and with aptitude remove commands add `+` after the package name to have it *installed*.

If you enter

```
sudo aptitude install cheese gthumb-
```

`cheese` will be installed while `gthumb` will be removed.

However, on the other hand, if you use

```
sudo aptitude remove grsync+ htop
```

`htop` will be removed and `grsync` installed.

Source: see the [Debian handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/download/stable/debian-handbook.pdf) for more information on `aptitude`.
For another essential explanation of `aptitude` and its other useful commands, see `man aptitude` or the [Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/aptitude.8.html) online.